# Problem with Linkedin API v2 permission mapping?

Tags: linkedin-api

Problem mapping permissions <-> endpoints ?

With the coming of LinkedinAPI v2 there are many questions and concern regarding how users should migrate or use V2.

After some time Linkedin updated their documentation for V2, however it still lack some important information.

So how do we know what are endpoints in permissions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, to the time of article the permission `nw_nus` was deprecated in favor of 4 new permissions:

1. r_member_social
2. w_member_social
3. w_organization_social
4. r_organization_social

For each endpoint, it's pretty self explanatory. But if you need details - copy it like "Linkedin FINDER owners /shares" into your search engine and it will take you to the Linkedin doc.

Below please find endpoints grouped by permission.
In any question do not hesitate to create support ticket :)
https://linkedin.zendesk.com/hc/en-us

**r_member_social**: Retrieve your posts, comments, likes, and other engagement data:

```
FINDER owners /shares
BATCH_GET /shares
GET /shares/{shareId}
BATCH_GET /socialActions
GET /socialActions/{target}
BATCH_GET /socialActions/{target}/comments
GET_ALL /socialActions/{target}/comments
GET /socialActions/{target}/comments/{commentId}
BATCH_GET /socialActions/{target}/likes
GET_ALL /socialActions/{target}/likes
BATCH_GET /activities
BATCH_GET /ugcPosts
FINDER authors /ugcPosts
FINDER permalinkSuffixes /ugcPosts
GET /ugcPosts/{id}
GET /assets/{assetId}
FINDER playableStreams /assets/{assetId}/mediaArtifactPublicUrls
```

**w_member_social**: Post, comment and like posts on your behalf:

```
CREATE /shares
DELETE /shares/{shareId}
PARTIAL_UPDATE /shares/{shareId}
CREATE /socialActions/{target}/comments
DELETE /socialActions/{target}/comments/{commentId}
CREATE /socialActions/{target}/likes
DELETE /socialActions/{target}/likes/{liker}
CREATE /ugcPosts
DELETE /ugcPosts/{id}
ACTION registerUpload /assets
ACTION completeMultipartUpload /assets
GET /assets/{assetId}
FINDER playableStreams /assets/{assetId}/mediaArtifactPublicUrls
```

**r_organization_social**: Retrieve your organizations' posts, including any comments, likes and other engagement data:

```
FINDER owners /shares
FINDER owners /shares
BATCH_GET /shares
GET /shares/{shareId}
BATCH_GET /socialActions
GET /socialActions/{target}
BATCH_GET /socialActions/{target}/comments
GET_ALL /socialActions/{target}/comments
GET /socialActions/{target}/comments/{commentId}
BATCH_GET /socialActions/{target}/likes
GET_ALL /socialActions/{target}/likes
BATCH_GET /activities
BATCH_GET /ugcPosts
FINDER permalinkSuffixes /ugcPosts
GET /ugcPosts/{id}
GET /assets/{assetId}
FINDER playableStreams /assets/{assetId}/mediaArtifactPublicUrls
BATCH_GET /sharesV2
```

**w_organization_social**: Post, comment and like posts on your organization's behalf:

```
CREATE /shares
DELETE /shares/{shareId}
PARTIAL_UPDATE /shares/{shareId}
CREATE /socialActions/{target}/comments
DELETE /socialActions/{target}/comments/{commentId}
CREATE /socialActions/{target}/likes
DELETE /socialActions/{target}/likes/{liker}
CREATE /ugcPosts
DELETE /ugcPosts/{id}
ACTION registerUpload /assets
ACTION completeMultipartUpload /assets
GET /assets/{assetId}
FINDER playableStreams /assets/{assetId}/mediaArtifactPublicUrls
```